# Integration of weird functions

Tags: real-analysis, integration, uniform-convergence

I know the heading may be a bit misleading one. But I can't find a better one. Anyone can suggest a good one.

By writing **Weird function** I mean those functions that are integrable but not easy to do so. I have come to know that uniform convergence of a series of integrable functions on some set confirms the fact that we can interchange the order of sum and integral. In other words, this leads to perform term by term integration for infinite series of functions. I am very curious about: **Can we write any weird function as the limiting function of uniformly convergent series of simple integrable functions?** If the answer is yes, then I think we can integrate those functions easily. But then after integrating we again have a series, that must be again uniformly convergent I think. In that case it may not be possible to write it as closed form. Is my observation is correct?

Comment: Are you asking "are there hard-to-solve integrals that are made easier using uniform convergence of a sequence of integrals?" As written, this is a lot of vague words that lead the reader down the wrong path, starting with the choice of words, "weird."

Comment: I hope there must exist such integrals that can be solved using the uniform convergence of sequence of integrals. But my question is a bit generalized i.e. can we do it for any of those "hard-to-solve" integrals ? Is there any general process to do so? In other words, can we write any function as the sum of a uniform convergent series of relatively simpler functions ?